# [F#][sharppcap][Error] "A type instantiation involves a byref type." what is a workaround in F#

Tags: f#, byref

I try to use SharpPcap in F#, but I was blocked by this compiler error for two days.

I find the most releate answer is [What is the error "A type instantiation involves a byref type." and what is a workaround in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405249/what-is-the-error-a-type-instantiation-involves-a-byref-type-and-what-is-a-wo), but do not fit my context well.

Please help me work around it, Thank you!

```ml
open System
open SharpPcap
open SharpPcap.LibPcap

let device = new CaptureFileReaderDevice("test.pcap")

// try workaround 1
let new_package (sender: Object) (e: PacketCapture) = ()
let handler = new PacketArrivalEventHandler(new_package)
device.OnPacketArrival.AddHandler(handler)
// error: A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.
```

```ml
// try workaround 2
let new_package (e: PacketCapture) = ()
device.OnPacketArrival.Add(new_package)
// error: A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.
```

I think the error is because:

```cs
public event PacketArrivalEventHandler OnPacketArrival;
public delegate void PacketArrivalEventHandler(object sender, PacketCapture e);
public readonly ref struct PacketCapture
{...}
```

The delegate `PacketArrivalEventHandler` use `PacketCapture` as param type, but this is a `readonly ref struct` which can not use to define F# function to add to Event `OnPacketArrival`.

Pls help me workaround it, Thank you!

I want make this line pass the F# compiler:

> device.OnPacketArrival.Add(new_package)

In c# it used in this way:

> device.OnPacketArrival += new_package

> [FS0412] A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.

Comment: Which part of the above can you change?

Comment: Please read the bottom section of this page and then fix your question with an edit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: @Fildor I want to fix that compiler error of this line `device.OnPacketArrival.Add(new_package)`

Comment: I figured that. But are you allowed to _change_ C# _and_ F# code or just one of either side?

Comment: @Fildor I get your point, I want to change F# code, not C# part.

Because I think this C# package design is good, the issue is calling C# function from F# side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this by using the F# `IEvent` first-class listening points, because in this case the type of `device.OnPacketArrival` ends up being `IEvent<PacketArrivalEventHandler, ref<PacketCapture>>`, whose second type parameter `ref<PacketCapture>` is not allowed. This is what the error message tells you.

But you can use the underlying .NET `add_` and `remove_` methods, which are analogs of property `get_` and `set_` methods, but for events. F# allows you to call these "hidden" methods explicitly, even though they're not listed in IDE completion lists.

```
device.add_OnPacketArrival handler
```

It works, because it's directly calling a method on the `device` object, rather than creating a wrapping value of type `IEvent<...>` and then calling `.Add` or `.AddHandler` on it.

Comment: BTW, Could you pls tell me where I can learn this knowledge: `F# allows you to call these "hidden" methods explicitly, even though they're not listed in IDE completion lists.`. 

I searched on Google to try to fix my issue for two days, do not find a way to lead me to this answer.

Comment: My knowledge of these methods comes from spelunking the IL via tools like ILSpy and .NET Reflector (back when it was free), and then confirming by experimentation. I am not aware of any particular places on the Internet that discuss these things. Perhaps C# or IL spec would? I'm pretty sure it should.